# If a set maximize difference, then probability are zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu, \nu$ be two finite measure on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ such that $\nu$ has density $f \in L^1$ w.r.t. $\mu$. Suppose that for any $\alpha > 0$ it exists a set $A_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}$ such that
\begin{align}
\nu(A) - \alpha \cdot \mu(A) \leq \nu(A_{\alpha}) - \alpha \cdot\mu(A_{\alpha}) \qquad \qquad  (1)
\end{align}
for any $A \in \mathcal{E}$. Show that
$$\mu(A_{\alpha} \cap \{f < \alpha\}) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \mu(\{f > \alpha\} \cap A_{\alpha}^c) =0$$

I wrote the difference $\lambda:= \nu - \alpha \cdot \mu$ has a finite signed measure with density $g:= f - \alpha \cdot id  \, $  w.r.t. $\mu$ and I tried to work with the inequality that we have in $(1)$ without success.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try rearranging the terms so that the $\mu$'s are on one side and the $\nu$'s are on the other side and choose something like $A =\{f> \alpha\}$ or $A=\{f>\alpha\}\cap A_\alpha$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove the second part. The first part similar.

$\int_A(f-\alpha)d\mu \leq \int_{A(\alpha)} (f-\alpha)d\mu$ for any $A$. This implies that $\int (f-\alpha)^{+} d\mu \leq \int_{A(\alpha)} (f-\alpha)^{+}d\mu$. [You get this by  taking $A=\{x: f(x) >\alpha\}$].

Hence $\int_{A(\alpha)^{c}} (f-\alpha)^{+}d\mu=0$. This implies that $\mu \{x: f(x) >\alpha, x \in A(\alpha)^{c}\}=0$.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!